# How to only show one content type with Content access

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I'm using the "Content Access" Module. I have created a user call "PriceUser" which I want to only be able to see the content of the content type "Price".

ie "PriceUser" goes to "/admin/content" and can only view price content.

so in order for "PriceUsers" to just view contentType "FundPrice" i need to uncheck "administer nodes"

i then go "/admin/content/node-type/price/access" and give update the permission per node.

My problem is that when i login as "PriceUser" i cannot see the content.

Answer (score 0):

> ie "PriceUser" goes to "/admin/content" and can only view price content.

First off, pages under /admin are thought for users with administrative permissions, and not for generic users; you should also be careful to assign such permissions to trusted users.
if you want to allow users to see the content of your site, then you should create a view using the Views module.

> so in order for "PriceUsers" to just view contentType "FundPrice" i need to uncheck "administer nodes"
>   My problem is that when i login as "PriceUser" i cannot see the content.

The page on /admin/content is only accessible from users who have the permission to administer nodes (or the user #1, which has all the permissions); as you removed that permission from the user account, the page is not anymore accessible.